# Simulate click and set guest in checkout/onepage/ (skipping first step)

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, checkout, onepage-checkout, javascript

I was wondering, can we (and how) emulate a click and set guest in checkout/onepage/ (skipping first step)

Ofcourse there is a plugin, but we have had some bad experiences with this (Crius skipstep) working on and off (and related to responsive theme)

Ideally: could we keep first step, but directly onload emulate a SET TO GUEST and CLICK NEXT

Thx!

Comment: Are you doing this for testing, trying to pre-select guest for the customer, or are you trying to force all checkouts to guest checkout?

Comment: Was this the extension? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/skip-checkout-step-1.html

Comment: Well, yes a little. We have the pre-select already. Now looking for a way to trigger next. And YES that was the extension. But it doesnt work well on latest Mage

Comment: Simulating the click is really a bad idea if you want to skip a step. Just skip the step.

Comment: Thx Fabian. But that is also where it becomes more problematic and breaking the checkout is easily accomplished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to simulate click events a few times and the best solution for Magento (since it is based on Prototype) was event.simulate.js - https://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/5b56fdafcd7d7662c9d648534225039b2e78e371/event.simulate.js

You only need to include the javascript and then you can simulate clicks like:

```
$('foo').simulate('click');
```

Comment: how to use it in Magento2